# Reserving a second boot partition for possible future windows

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning

Ok, here is the issue:

I have a freshly built desktop and want to install Ubuntu studio with live USB. So far no problem. I don't know if I will have to install windows in the future again, but just to give me the option, I would like to make a partition for Ubuntu, one for (possible) future Windows and one for files. Finally, a fourth one for boot loader that just serves the purpose of picking which OS partition to pick.

All guides I have seen are insisting I install windows, download Ubuntu and make a new partition then. Is that really the only way? Because if so, it's not happening. Maybe there is an obvious answer I am missing, but yeah.

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI This is what you need to understand first of all. Once understood it should be easy to create a dual-boot anytime and regardless of which OS is installed first. Do not create a "partition for Windows", there's no need. Leave unallocated space for that purpose. Learn about partitions and OS requirements. Start by making sure the target drive is GPT, etc.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand? It seems to me by ensuring installation in UEFI mode, that the ESP becomes essentially the boot loader partition. But wouldn't I still need two primary partitions? I know Ubuntu and Windows can't be in the same one and I don't see anything in the documentation about being able to set up a new primary partition. I have been trying to make sense of that issue but it doesn't seem to be addressed.

Comment: The ESP (EFI System Partition) is indeed where ALL bootloaders are saved and it has a "boot" flag (for Windows, Ubuntu doesn't need flags).  Primary and extended are concepts that make no sense in GPT (and you need GPT for Windows in UEFI mode, Ubuntu doesn't care but perhaps it should). So, again, make sure the drive is GPT (use GParted > Devices menu > Create new... > choose "GPT") and make sure the installer is booting in UEFI mode, that's all.

Comment: Windows in UEFI boot mode requires gpt and several partitions. Best just to let Windows create the partitions it wants. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/configure-uefigpt-based-hard-drive-partitions#RecommendedPartitionConfigurations